# In what ways does Allah communicate with us?

Tags: allah, dua

In what ways does Allah communicate with us? If we have a problem, for example, and we ask Allah to provide a solution to our problems, but we can't think of any, how does Allah communicate with us?

Would it be through dreams, or would the solution come into our hearts?

Comment: Allah guides you in resolving your problems, not necessarily how you want. Seek HIS help in easing the burden of you difficulties. He will guide you. Dreams are dreams.

Comment: Perhaps the clue is in the name. Does not Al-Lah mean The One? Communication would require two, Does the solution "'come into our hearts" or is it there all the time?

Answer (score 5):

> It is not given to any human being that Allah should speak to him unless (it be) by **Inspiration, or from behind a veil, or (that) He sends a Messenger** to reveal what He wills by His Leave. Verily, He is Most High, Most Wise. (Qur'an 42:51)

Inspiration could be through many ways, through signs ([Qur'an 5:31](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=5&verse=31)) which we can see, through dreams ([Qur'an 37:105](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=37&verse=105)) and also through guidance via Qur'an and the words of Prophet (peace be upon him). We ought to be careful though in deciding if a certain dream or a sign is from Allah as we might not possess a good ability to filter out the good dreams / signs from the bad ones.

Often times we take decisions based on our wisdom, guidance and Furqan (intellect, the ability to decide if something is right or wrong). Isn't it mainly obtained from Qur'an and Hadith?

> But those who deny Our verses are deaf and dumb within darknesses. **Whomever Allah wills - He leaves astray; and whomever He wills - He puts him on a straight path.** (Qur'an 6:39)

So, we need to try as much as possible to read the Qur'an and try to get guidance,

Perhaps the best description of the Quran was given by Hazrat Ali(RA), the cousin of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) when he expounded upon it as,

> "The Book of God. In it is the record of what was before you, the judgment of what is among you, and the prophecies of what will come after you. It is decisive, not a case for levity. Whoever is a tyrant and ignores the Quran will be destroyed by God. Whoever seeks guidance from other than it will be misguided. **The Quran is the unbreakable bond of connection with God; it is the remembrance full of wisdom and the straight path**. The Quran does not become distorted by tongues, nor can it be deviated by caprices; it never dulls from repeated study; scholars will always want more of it. The wonders of the Quran are never ending. Whoever speaks from it will speak the truth, whoever rules with it will be just, and **whoever holds fast to it will be guided to the straight path.**"
>   [At-Tirmidhi]

We constantly keep asking Allah's guidance in every rakah of every Salah.

> All the praises and thanks be to Allah, the Lord of the 'Alamin (mankind, jinns and all that exists). The Most Beneficent, the Most Merciful. The Only Owner of the Day of Recompense(Judgement), You (Alone) we worship, and you (Alone) we ask for help (for each and everything). **Guide us to the Straight Way(path), The Way of those on whom You have bestowed Your Grace , not (the way) of those who earned Your Anger, nor of those who went astray.**

Sometimes, consulting our friends or near of kin can help. ([Qur'an 42:38](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=42&verse=38))

Sometimes, we do not have the complete picture of what could be coming on our way, or we're in a dilemma and are unable to get out of. I think Istikhara is one way which is prescribed by Prophet (peace be upon him).

> Narrated Jabir bin Abdullah:
>   The Prophet (p.b.u.h) used to teach us the way of doing Istikhara (Istikhara means to ask Allah to guide one to the right sort of action concerning any job or a deed), in all matters as he taught us the Suras of the Qur'an. He said, "If anyone of you thinks of doing any job he should offer a two rakat prayer other than the compulsory ones and say (after the prayer): -- '*Allahumma inni astakhiruka biilmika, Wa astaqdiruka bi-qudratika, Wa as'alaka min fadlika Al-azlm Fa-innaka taqdiru Wala aqdiru, Wa ta'lamu Wala a'lamu, Wa anta 'allamu l-ghuyub. Allahumma, in kunta ta'lam anna hadha-lamra Khairun li fi dini wa ma'ashi wa'aqibati Amri (or 'ajili Amri wa'ajilihi) Faqdirhu wa yas-sirhu li thumma barik li Fihi, Wa in kunta ta'lamu anna hadha-lamra shar-run li fi dini wa ma'ashi wa'aqibati Amri (or fi'ajili Amri wa ajilihi) Fasrifhu anni was-rifni anhu. Waqdir li al-khaira haithu kana Thumma ardini bihi.' (O Allah! I ask guidance from Your knowledge, And Power from Your Might and I ask for Your great blessings. You are capable and I am not. You know and I do not and You know the unseen. O Allah! If You know that this job is good for my religion and my subsistence and in my Hereafter--(or said: If it is better for my present and later needs)--Then You ordain it for me and make it easy for me to get, And then bless me in it, and if You know that this job is harmful to me In my religion and subsistence and in the Hereafter--(or said: If it is worse for my present and later needs)--Then keep it away from me and let me be away from it. And ordain for me whatever is good for me, And make me satisfied with it)*. The Prophet (ﷺ) added that then the person should name (mention) his need. ([Sahih al-Bukhari 1166](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/19/45))

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 1):

**There could be some ways that Allah indicates us some solutions. As you mentioned, dreams could be helpful in showing the truths and solutions, of course not always. Since we cannot trust dreams constantly, but there are a sort of dreams which is called truthful dream that could be considered as a truth ...**

As I pointed, you ought not to trust each dream, Since there are some factors to be able to trust the dreams as truthful dream. For instance, as a factor of truthful dreams, Allamah Majlesi, as a scholar of Shia narrates that:

> The truthful dream is seen at the last Tholth (ثلث) (the last third) of
> the night, Since that is the time which Malaekah(angels) come down …
>
> (Allamah Muhammad Baqir Majlesi, Qom, Heliatul Mottaqin, Page246)
> .(علامه محمد باقر مجلسي، حلية المتقين (قم، انتشارات هجرت، 1373) ص 246.
> )

But another way which could help us, is related to Istekharah (الاستخاره).

In fact, Istekharah will show us the right route. Actually it could be considered as a consultation with Allah.

---

**Reference**:

- [www.porsemanequran.com](http://www.porsemanequran.com/node/22991)

Answer (score 0):

Allah communicate with the Quran and the messenger. Dreams is just a dreams, even some dream can be controlled as the context of Lucid Dream, so you should not trust any dreams.

Allah did not communicate to us directly, but Allah put something in our heart to make us sure about what we do. Allah manage your life, without even need to say anything.

Answer (score 0):

By rain as a sign ie if you do Zikr about something and then it starts raining when you do the Zikr, it is one of signs that that your Zikr is working. Also if you get an idea in your head or heart and it starts raining it is a sign from Allah that your idea will lead to some thing.

Comment: Any resource or proof of for answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Allah communicate with us by Quran pak. If you have any problem you should be recite Quran pak because in Quran pak Allah tell us solution of our every problem.

Answer (score -1):

Es selamu aleikum I would say that Allah speak to whom he whants through dreams do not forget that Allah spoke to Ibrahim peace be upon him ordered him to sacrifice his own child if Allah wishes to guide someone he will speak through dreams he will send an angel apering as his father ore as his dead grandfather 
Do not judge me if you think that I am wrong

Comment: Allah spoke to Ibrahim peace be on him through dreams